# Test Database not refreshing after running initial tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rspec2

I am going thru Railstutorial.org and having this issue:

Test Database seem to not be emptying after running tests.

In section 6.10 I create the line below in the user_spec.rb file and it passes the first time then fails every time afterwards.

```
it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
     User.create!(@attr)
end
```

When i look at the test.sqlite3 database it shows 1 user in the database. If I remove the user the test passes once, then fails again saying it cannot create the user because email is not unique.  I look in the Database and there the record is again.

It seems like that code above creates it, but it doesnt ever get destroyed.

Here is my GemFile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org' 
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'

group :development do 
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.3.0'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
end

group :test do 
    gem 'rspec', '2.3.0' 
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in `./spec/spec_helper.rb` and make sure the following line is there:

`config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [database_cleaner gem](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) and see if that solves your problem.